# powershell set-assignedaccess can't see user

Tags: windows, powershell

Why if I enter:

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppName ICI-App -UserSID S-1-5-21-1060284298-1677128483-1417001333-710280
```

[image]

The answer from powershell is user was not found?
I try the same with user instead UserSID and is the same effect.
[image]

user works in domain - windows 10

any ideas?

Comment: Please read the help about asking [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I think you should [enter image description here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)